# How to debug cfg80211.ko

Tags: ida, debugging, linux, debuggers, kernel

I have an Linux embedded device that I want to debug the cfg80211.ko

I have full root SSH on that device.

How can I debug cfg80211.ko?

Comment: Seeing as this is an embedded device you can't debug through a VM, so this needs local debugging. A couple of questions... do you have symbols for the running kernel, and can you install packages on this device?

Comment: What do you mean install a packages into device? I can run gdbserver etc. That Linux Arm embedded  @MegaTonnage

Comment: Added as an answer, however I haven't tested this recently and some of it likely won't be relevant to your embedded device.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my notes for Fedora here, maybe they'll help:

```
# ensure kernel core is configured
grep KCORE /boot/config-$(uname -r)

# install kernel debuginfo for symbols
dnf debuginfo-install kernel-core-$(uname -r)

# debug kernel using core file
gdb /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /proc/kcore

# find address
sudo cat /sys/module/<module>/sections/.text
<address>

# extract module if required
cp /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/<module>/host/<module>.ko.xz ./
xz -d <module>.ko.xz

# load mod symbols
add-symbol-file /root/<module>.ko <address>
```